# Is this an example of closure in JavaScript? Or what is happening and where can I read more about what is happening here?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, for-in-loop

```
let progresses = [93,30,55];    
let speeds = [1,30,5];  

    
for(let i in speeds) {
    console.log(progresses[i]); // [90, 30, 55]
}
```

Iterating over the speeds array, how is it possible to access the value of progresses array?

```
progresses.forEach((item, i) => {
    console.log(speeds[item]); // undefined
    console.log(speeds[i]); // [1,30, 5]
});
```

Iterating over progresses array, why is speeds[item] undefined and speeds[i] value accessible?

Comment: `console.log(i)` – `for in` loops should not be used on arrays like `speeds`, see [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea) Maybe you’re thinking of `for (let i of speeds)`?

Comment: `i` is an index. `item` is not.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have a misunderstanding of what `Array.forEach` does:

```
progresses.forEach((item, i) => {
    console.log(item);       // [93,30,55]
    console.log(speeds[i]);  // [1,30, 5]
});
```

The first argument passed to you is the item itself.

The reason you cannot access the items of `speed` is because you are asking for the 93rd item which does not exist so it returns undefined then you ask for `speed[30]` which also does not exist so it is undefined then you ask for `speed[55]` which again is undefined.

#### Follow-up

> When iterating over processes array, how is console.log(speeds[i]) possible?

Your code works by accident. When using for..in the variable you get is the properties of an object. In older versions of javascript, depending on the interpreter the following code:

```
for(let i in speeds) {
    console.log(progresses[i]);
}
```

Will get:

```
progress[0] // prints 93
progress[1] // prints 30
progress[2] // prints 55
progress['length'] // prints 3
progress['forEach'] // prints function
progress['map'] // prints function
.. etc
```

Newer versions of javascript made the change to array objects so that properties such as `length` and `forEach` are not `enumerable` (I didn't know they changed this myself until this question).

You can test that this is what happens by giving the two arrays different length:

```
let progresses = [93,30,55];    
let speeds = [1];  

    
for(let i of speeds) {
    console.log(progresses[i]); // [93]
}
```

In the code above the code only prints `93` instead of all three elements of the `progress` array because the `speed` array only has one element thus `i` is only ever assigned the value `0`.

> Note also that I am using for..of instead of for..in because for..of was designed to not return other properties of an array such as `length` and `forEach`. I know the current javascript does not do this with for..in but it's still a good idea to follow good practices since you can't really control what browser you users will use.

Comment: My questions is that I am using forEach on 'processes array', not on the 'speeds array' which is making the code confusing to understand. Why is it that when iterating over processes array, how is console.log(speeds[i]) possible?

Comment: Because for..in will give you the index of the process array